# How to store data in Powerbi for custom visual

Tags: typescript, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, pbiviz

For my PowerBI custom visual I want to store some data in the storage. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/local-storage#considerations-and-limitations) up to 1Mb are supported.
It works fine for just 3_000 zeros, but 30_000 zeros are failing with an undefined error.
I use the `Developer Visual` to display my custom visual for debugging.

I tried storing data and then reading it (in the visual update) via:

```js
public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
//...        
        // try loading data
        this.storageService.get("storage").then(data =>{
            console.log("Loaded storage: ", data);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.error(err);
        });
        
        // remove any previous data
        this.storageService.remove("storage");
        // create sample data
        let content = '0'.repeat(30_000);
        // set storage data
        this.storageService.set("storage", content).then(f =>{
            console.log("Setting storage ... Finished!");                                
        })
        .catch(ex=>{
            console.error(ex); // Line 102
        });
//...
}
```

When saving the 30_000 character I get an "undefined" error:

```
visual.ts:102 
        
       undefined
(anonymous) @ visual.ts:102
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:12
(anonymous) @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
c @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
fireWith @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
(anonymous) @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
c @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
fireWith @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
i.reject @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:12
e.RejectPromise @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
m.handleSetStorageData @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
m.executeMessage @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
m.onMessageReceived @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
n.invokeHandler @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
n.dispatchMessage @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
n.onMessageReceived @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
windowMessageHandler @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
dispatch @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
v.handle @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
postMessage (async)
n.sendMessage @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:16
n.postMessage @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:16
e.postMessage @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
V.setStorageData @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
e.setStorageData @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
e.onMessageReceived @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
n.invokeHandler @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:16
n.dispatchMessage @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:16
n.onMessageReceived @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:16
windowMessageHandler @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:16
dispatch @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
v.handle @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
t.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Ve.invokeTask @ web.min.386bab8ebb751022ba05.js:1
e.runTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
g @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
y @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
postMessage (async)
n.sendMessage @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
n.postMessage @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
t.setStorageData @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
e.set @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
update @ visual.ts:98
update @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
t.trackVisualTime @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
t.update @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
n @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:12
__awaiter @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
n @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:12
__awaiter @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
o.executeSafelyAsync @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
o.update @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
m.fixUpdateOptionsAndUpdateVisual @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
m.update @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
m.executeMessage @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
m.onMessageReceived @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
(anonymous) @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:20
n.invokeHandler @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
n.dispatchMessage @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
n.onMessageReceived @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
windowMessageHandler @ customVisualsHost.bundle.min.js:19
dispatch @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
v.handle @ visualsandbox.minimal.externals.min.js:146
postMessage (async)
n.flushQueue @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:16
e.ready @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
e.onIFrameLoad @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
i @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
dispatch @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
v.handle @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
t.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Ve.invokeTask @ web.min.386bab8ebb751022ba05.js:1
e.runTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
g @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
y @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
load (async)
R @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleEventTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
add @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
each @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
each @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
ke @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
one @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
e.initContainer @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
i.<computed> @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Ve.invokeTask @ web.min.386bab8ebb751022ba05.js:1
e.runTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
invoke @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
n.args.<computed> @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
setTimeout (async)
c @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleMacroTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
v @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
A.i.<computed> @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.init @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
t.invoke @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Ve.invoke @ web.min.386bab8ebb751022ba05.js:1
e.run @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Ve.invokeTask @ web.min.386bab8ebb751022ba05.js:1
e.runTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
m @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
g @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
y @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
load (async)
R @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleEventTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
i.set @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
send @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
ajax @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
S.each.S.<computed> @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
c @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
fireWith @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
l @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
x @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Ve.invokeTask @ web.min.386bab8ebb751022ba05.js:1
e.runTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
g @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
y @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
load (async)
R @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleEventTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
i.set @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
send @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
ajax @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
c @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
fireWith @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
l @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
x @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Ve.invokeTask @ web.min.386bab8ebb751022ba05.js:1
e.runTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
g @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
y @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
load (async)
R @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleEventTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
i.set @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
send @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
ajax @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
S.each.S.<computed> @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
getJSON @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
c @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
fireWith @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
l @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
x @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Ve.invokeTask @ web.min.386bab8ebb751022ba05.js:1
e.runTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
g @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
y @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
load (async)
R @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
t.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.scheduleEventTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
i.set @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
send @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
ajax @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
S.each.S.<computed> @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
i.reloadAdapter @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
(anonymous) @ powerbiportal.common.bundle.min.dec6934de4d55e7f019f.js:18
dispatch @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
v.handle @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:7
t.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Ve.invokeTask @ web.min.386bab8ebb751022ba05.js:1
e.runTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
e.invokeTask @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
g @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
y @ powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.9334277c97a1912dee40.js:5
Show 35 more frames
```

#### Update

Now I cleaned my browsers local storage and session storage with:

```js
localStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.clear();
```

It increased the amount I'm able to save at once to 60_000. But when writing 50_000 and 9_000 it still fails with the same error (directly after that remove and write 60_000 is working).

My current assumption is, that only ~60kb are available for the custom visuals.

Comment: Quite possibly you're hitting some internal limit for serializing/deserializing the value itself through a fixed buffer of what someone thought was a reasonable size, even though this isn't documented. Try creating 10 values of 3000 characters -- if that works you can be fairly sure it's not the 1 MB overall limit that's being hit.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It seems like there is some soft-limit between 50k and 60k ... I cleaned my localstorage and sessionstorage, then I was able to write more than 3000 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Info

I solved my problem by reworking the access to external data by removing the dependency on using the PowerBI storage in the visual.
This also enables me to store more data than 1mb.

#### My workaround

The data I want to storage I now moved to a separate Azure Storage Blob and created a new SAS (Shared Access Signature) for accessing the blob. Next hurdle is that the fetch request is blocked by cors so we need to configure `Allowed origins = null`, `Allowed methods = GET` and `Max age = 200`.

To the settings I added an option in the `capabilities.json`, to let me configure a url which I can query.

```json
"objects":   {
        "general": {
            "displayName": "General settings",
            "properties": {
                "myurl": {
                    "displayName": "Url where data is stored.",
                    "type": { "text": true }
                }
            }
        },
...
```

Then make sure the settings are displayed to the user for the custom visual by adding the following method to `visual.ts`:

```js
export class Visual implements IVisual {
// ...

    // This is needed to ensure the settings are displayed on the Format-Tab
    public enumerateObjectInstances(options: EnumerateVisualObjectInstancesOptions): VisualObjectInstance[] | VisualObjectInstanceEnumerationObject {
        return VisualSettings.enumerateObjectInstances(this.settings || VisualSettings.getDefault(), options);
    }
```

When everything is configured we can use the fetch api in typescript to get the data and further process it.

```js
private async GetData(): Promise<string> {
let url = this.settings.general.myurl;
if (url) {
    try {
        let resp = await fetch(url, {
                referrer: "https://app.powerbi.com",
                headers: {
                    // "Origin": "https://app.powerbi.com", // PowerBI sets this to null
                }
            });

        let txt = await resp.text();
        return Promise.resolve(txt);
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject("Request failed.");
    }
}
return Promise.reject("No url defined.");
}
```

For the write we just need to add the following to the cors configuration: `Allowed origins = null`, `Allowed methods = PUT`, `Allowed headers=authorization,x-ms-blob-content-disposition,x-ms-blob-type,x-ms-date,x-ms-meta-m1,x-ms-meta-m2,x-ms-version` and `Exposed headers = x-ms-blob*`.
Then we can use the REST API to upload the data.

```js
private async SetData(data: string): Promise<void> {
        let url = this.settings.general.saveurl; // URL with SAS token
        if (url) {
            try {
                let resp = await fetch(url, {
                    referrer: "https://app.powerbi.com",
                    headers: {
                        // "Origin": "https://app.powerbi.com", // PowerBI sets this to null
                        "x-ms-version": "2017-11-09",
                        "x-ms-date": new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0],
                        "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
                        "x-ms-blob-content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"mydata.txt\"",
                        "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
                        "x-ms-meta-m1": "v1",
                        "x-ms-meta-m2": "v2",
                        // "Authorization": "SharedKey myaccount:..." // not needed with sas token
                    },
                    method: "PUT",
                    body: data
                });
                return Promise.resolve();
            } catch (err) {
                return Promise.reject("Request failed.");
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject("No save url defined.");
    }
```